# Borel sets of extended real line

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Folland's real analysis, the paragraph that introduces Borel sets of the extended real line says

> The extended real line is defined by $\overline{\mathbb{R}}:={\mathbb{R}}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$.
>
> We define Borel sets in the extended real line  by
> $\mathcal{B}_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}} = \{ E \mid E \cap \mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}} \}$. This coincides with the usual definition of Borel $\sigma$-algebra if we make $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ into a metric space with metric $d(x, y) = |\arctan x - \arctan y|$.

May I ask why the authors say "This coincides with the usual definition of Borel $\sigma$-algebra"? Is it necessary to define a metric for $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ to obtain its Borel sets? Thanks!

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566488/open-sets-and-borel-sets-on-the-extended-real-line?rq=1

Comment: You need a topology on the extended real line in order to define a Borel sigma algebra. Though IMO this is a strange way to define a topology on it.

Comment: I wish this question would define $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Answer (score 2):

For purposes of the paragraph that you cited, a metric on $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is a very handy way to define a topology on $\overline{\mathbb R}$. In other words, it is a handy way to determine what are the open subsets of $\overline{\mathbb R}$.

And it is certainly necessary to know the open subsets, in order to define the Borel sets. Remember: by definition the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (of a topological space; or of a metric space) is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that every open set is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra.